# Can I get Dialogflow send a request to my webhook when I trigger an event?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to trigger an intent/event in Dialogflow [from my webhook/server] and have Dialogflow send a request to my /webhook instead of just responding to the POST request that I made which triggered the event. Is that possible? I want to send the user a message based on their input in our web application, but the response types could vary greatly so I can't define the message and payload in the DF web panel.

edit: [in brackets]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dialogflow can send information to a webhook - it refers to this as [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

Keep in mind that the JSON sent by Dialogflow will be in its format, not yours, and it expects a reply in its format as well. This reply will include the message to be sent back to the user (the response to the original POST request).